# What is this Eastern European military uniform?

Tags: military, europe, identification, uniform

These photographs are of my great-granduncle who lived in the village of Velyki Laz, just outside of Uzhhorod in today's western Ukraine. He was born in 1905. I would like to identify the uniforms that he is wearing in each. I am guessing that the uniforms are either Austro-Hungarian Empire, Czechoslovakian or Kingdom of Hungary. By the 1940's he was a refugee in Bavaria.

[image: man in uniform]

[image: man in uniform]

Comment: Is it possible to add a high resolution image of the cap badge? That would likely aid immensely, and might even identify the regiment.

Comment: It won't be Austro-Hungarian as that Empire ceased to exist in 1918 when the subject would have been 13 years old.

Comment: I wish I was able to provide a better picture, but unfortunately this is the best that I have.

Comment: Romanian, maybe?  The shape of the pocket flaps seems to match some of these in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgg7RMOENaA&ab_channel=TheGreatWar .